# Get CityCode By IP from GeoIP2 City Database

Tags: maxmind

Is there any way of utilizing maxmind in order to get city codes via the IP of the user ?

In the following example, I am able to get the name of the City but not cityCodes. As far as I know maxmind does not have a support for city codes ;

Ref for maxmind support : https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city

**E.g;**

```
private static DatabaseReader reader = null;
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);         
CityResponse response = reader.city(inetAddress);
String cityName = response.getCity().getName(); //Istanbul
String cityCode = response.getCity().???code???; // The desired output : IST
```

Comment: Which "city codes" in particular are you referring to? I am not aware of ISO city codes. There are the UN/LOCODE, the IATA codes, and perhaps others. The former might be doable using data from GeoNames.

Comment: Sorry for the prev. comment of mine, it is not IATA codes that I'm out after. I would like to have a standardization If there is any global standard of city codes.  NY for Newyork, DUB for Dublin etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the [UN/LOCODE](http://www.unece.org/cefact/locode/welcome.html) is the closest match to what you are asking for. MaxMind itself does not provide these codes in its data set, but it does provide a `geoname_id` for the city that can be used to look up the city in the [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) data set. GeoNames provides UN/LOCODE in their [premium data set](http://www.geonames.org/products/premium-data.html).